$\mathbb{C}G$-modules and $\mathbb{C}^{G}$-comodules
I know that representations of a group $G$ are essentially $\mathbb{C}G$-modules. How is it that every $\mathbb{C}G-$module is also equivalent to a $\mathbb{C}^{G}-$comodule. I have not found this relationship in the literature, I would appreciate your help in pointing out how this construction is done.

What is the definition of $\mathbf{C}^G$?

@Stephen functions from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

That's the usual definition of the group ring $\mathbf{C} G$ (with convolution as the multiplication). Perhaps you mean to take $\mathbf{C}^G$ to be the linear dual of the group ring, as a cogebra? In that case comodules for it are the same as modules for the group ring, essentially by definition.
